# TypeScript interface field is set, but shows undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm honestly really confused now.
I have such code:

```
console.log(socket);
console.log(socket.id);
```

Produces such output in console:

[image: code output]

interface looks like this:

```
export interface Socket {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

I feel like answer is very obvious, but can't really think of any reason why id prints as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out logging object itself is wrong. Id is probably set later, because printing `Object.keys(socket)` does not show id.